# how can I place multiples models in one view?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have 4 models with same fields name. I need to show records from the 4 models on one view

how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Odoo view is usually a representation of a record in the database. To accomplish what you are speaking of you need to create a view which is the representation of a record which has relationships to all the other records you are speaking of. So a hackish way would be to create a model with 4 many2one fields each point at the model and records you are referring to.

Another option is to create a custom view or widget and using javascript to gather the data you need using the Odoo javascript api and then rendering it in a fashion that makes it usable for your use case.

This all depends on what you are trying to accomplish by displaying the 4 records. If it is simply a matter of displaying some information to the user a wizard model (models.TransientModel) with 4 many2one values may accomplish what you need.

Comment: I think you meant `TransientModel` for wizard?